# Make coordinates of draggable element relative to droppable element after appending to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm trying to make a tool for a website that uses draggable and droppable elements, from jQueryUI.

I have one `div` that contains the elements (draggables) and a `div` that the elements will be moved to (droppable). They are completely separate `div`s and once an element gets dropped into the droppable `div` it needs to be moved there.

I have code that works for moving it over, getting the droppable to accept the correct stuff, and even code to keep the draggable element draggable only in the droppable `div`. The issue arises when you initially drag the draggable element to the droppable `div`.

It retains the coordinates from the original `div` that contains the draggable elements. So, when I append it to the new element it appears offset a bunch. I can move it into the droppable `div` after that just fine and it works as expected, but doesn't help much if it can't be there from the start.

Is there no way of just having it convert the coordinates to match that of the droppable `div` so it appears in the same spot on the page but is inside the droppable `div` on the DOM?

Example:

HTML

```
<div id="MoveZone" class="Container">
    <div id="MoveMe"></div>
</div>
<div style="height: 10px;"></div>
<div id="DropZone" class="Container"></div>
```

CSS

```
.Container {
    outline-style: solid;
    outline-color: black;
    outline-width: 3px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
#MoveMe {
    outline-style: solid;
    outline-color: blue;
    outline-width: 2px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: ghostwhite;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#MoveMe').draggable({
        revert: 'invalid'
    });
    $('#DropZone').droppable({
        accept: '#MoveZone div, #DropZone div',
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this));
            ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'containment', 'parent');
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meishe91/drx9ejoo/)

I did find one way to do it, sort of. But it requires hard coding in the droppable `div`'s id...which I don't particularly like. Also, when it gets dropped it slightly offsets to the upper-left, so even then it's not perfect because if it get's put in the top-left corner it will be partially out of the box.

[Other Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meishe91/drx9ejoo/1/)

EDIT:
The only other way I can think of doing it is some how calculating the offset between the boxes and adjusting the location in the drop method. But I'm not sure how I'd go about that, especially since on my site the location of the droppable spot won't be static. (It's centered in the page, so could move slightly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution that solves the issue. The following JavaScript is what does it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#MoveMe').draggable({
        revert: 'invalid',
        cursor: 'move'
    });
    $('#DropZone').droppable({
        accept: '#MoveZone div, #DropZone div',
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var parent = ui.draggable.parent();
            var draggedElement = $(ui.draggable);
            var dropZone = $(this);

            var leftOffset = Math.abs(parent.offset().left - dropZone.offset().left);
            var topOffset = dropZone.offset().top - parent.offset().top;

            draggedElement.detach().appendTo(dropZone);

            draggedElement.css('left', draggedElement.position().left - leftOffset);
            draggedElement.css('top', draggedElement.position().top - topOffset);

            draggedElement.draggable('option', 'containment', 'parent');
        }

    });
});
```

Basically, what does it is that you just calculate the offset between the two `div` elements and when it get's appended to the droppable `div` you adjust the top and left CSS to that of the new one.

For some reason, it doesn't work in JSFiddle, but it does work.